# How to create [key, value]pairs within a RDD partition

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I get a problem about map within map,I've searched so many questions,and all the answers are "can't create RDD within RDD",well ,I need to create [key, value]pairs within a RDD partition, here is my question,for example:

a RDD has many partitions ,one of them is `[1 => (2,11, 3,333, 3,222)]`,for this partition ,I need to output  `[2 => 11],[3 => (333,222)]` ,what should I do ?

I think about

`RDD.map{case(key, value) => value.map(value(1)=>value(2)).groupByKey()}.groupByKey()`

But I don't know whether it'll works.

Thanks!

Comment: `reduceByKey` should work for you. Check out https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html

Comment: Some sample inputs and expected outputs shall help others to help you reach the solution.